# linux auto.nfs config gets updated periodically

Tags: linux, autofs

I' have little experience with linux autofs. I can't help but keep noticing that files in /etc/ timestamps change periodically.

From documentation, my understanding is fstab is supposedly fixed(configured once).

Is it normal? 
Sometimes programs writing to file (mounted fs) failed randomly.(no such file or directory).
I suspect some processes might be causing high load on nfs?

These are the files.

```
/etc/mtab
/etc/auto.fs
/etc/fstab
/etc/rsyncd.conf
```

Upon checking /var/log/messages, there are a lot of these with just 1 min apart.

```
autofs: automount startup succeeded
autofs: auto mount shutdown succeeded
autofs: automount startup succeeded
autofs: auto mount shutdown succeeded
...
```